# D3.js - exit() section does not remove all data

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I merged http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642 and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 d3 force layout examples into below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/*.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.a { fill: #1f77b4; }
.node.b { fill: #ff7f0e; }
.node.c { fill: #2ca02c; }*/

.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = {id: "a"}, b = {id: "b"}, c = {id: "c"};
  nodes.push(a, b, c);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: a, target: c}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function() {
  nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
  links.shift(); // remove a-b
  links.pop(); // remove b-c
  start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = nodes[0], b = {id: "b"}, c = nodes[1];
  nodes.push(b);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  //link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
  node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
  node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {console.log(d.id); return d.id;});
  //node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}

function tick() {
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}

</script>
```

After code execution some svg "g" nodes have multiple text and image children-nodes, although, as I suppouse, they should be removed in exit() section.

How can I fix it? Any help appreciated.

Edit:

Example of text and image nodes duplication:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(411.8420674597886,245.93226853324168)">
    <image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-8" y="-8" width="16" height="16"></image>
    <text dx="12" dy=".35em">a</text>
    <image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-8" y="-8" width="16" height="16"></image>
    <text dx="12" dy=".35em">a</text>
    <image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-8" y="-8" width="16" height="16"></image>
    <text dx="12" dy=".35em">a</text>
</g>
```

Edit2:
As @LarsKotthoff suggested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/*.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.a { fill: #1f77b4; }
.node.b { fill: #ff7f0e; }
.node.c { fill: #2ca02c; }*/

.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(120)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = {id: "a"}, b = {id: "b"}, c = {id: "c"};
  nodes.push(a, b, c);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: a, target: c}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function() {
  nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
  links.shift(); // remove a-b
  links.pop(); // remove b-c
  start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = nodes[0], b = {id: "b"}, c = nodes[1];
  nodes.push(b);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  //link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.enter().append("line").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
  var appendedG= node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  appendedG.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
  appendedG.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {console.log(d.id); return d.id;});
  //node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}

function tick() {
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });


  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}

</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're appending the `image` and `text` elements for the update and not the enter selection. Did you miss a `.enter()` in front of those `append`s?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Don't know if I understood properly. When I added node.enter().append("image") and node.enter().append("text") the <text> and <image> tags are not stored inside <g> tag any more. In addition I noticed that even though those tags are duplicated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save the result of the first `append` operation and append to that. At the moment, `nodes` is the result of the data matching and you're appending to two different selections within it, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff It worked! Thanks. Now I must check what has happened in the code bacause I don't understand it yet.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
var newNode = node.enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .call(force.drag);
newNode.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
newNode.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {console.log(d.id); return d.id;});
  //node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id;    }).attr("r", 8);
node.exit().remove();
```